# Rails client side validation working on submit action of all forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, client-side-validation

I am using rails client side validations gem, version 3.2.1. Right now, I have ran in to a problem where validations are now been applied on forms where I don't want these validations to be applied.

Please find out my two forms, for sign up and sign in.

```
_sign_up_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@user, :validate => true, :remote => true) do |f| %>

_sign_in_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@user_session, :remote => true) do |f| %
```

As you could see i have set validate => true only on my sign up form.

I want these client side validations to be working on sign_up form and not on the sign_in form. Please note that both these forms are loaded after ajax requests made to the 'new' action of the respective controllers.

_sign_up_form.html.erb is loaded when the users/new.js.erb is rendered

```
*users/new/js.erb*
$("#static-form-modal .modal-body").html('<%= j(render(:partial => "users/sign_up_form"))%>');
$('form').live("click",function() {
$(this).enableClientSideValidations();
});
```

_sign_in_form.html.erb is loaded when user_sessions/new.js.erb is rendered

```
*user_sessions/new.js.erb*
$('#static-form-modal .modal-body').html('<%= j(render(:partial => "user_sessions/sign_in_form"))%>');
```

The client side validations are working perfect in the sign up form and the error messages are displayed next to the error fields.

The problem is that **when i click the submit button of the sign in form, these validation error messages appear next to the error fields**. Server side valdiations obviously, but I am not able to figure to way to remove those error messages appearing next to the error fields.

Also, i am not simple form. I have uncommented these lines in the initializers/client_side_validations.rb .

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question I'd ask is if those error messages are wrong ? Or you would like to turn off the error messages in general ?

Comment: I would like to turn off the error messages in general. To be specific, when i click on the sign in form I don't want any error messages to be appearing besides the text fields.

Comment: I think that the main purpose of this gem is to display error messages besides the field . If you don't want to display them , probably should remove the gem . Give us more details . As I can see , your config is correct .

Comment: Yes, but what if want those error messages to be shown up in only certain forms and not in the others? Is there some way to check for the current form and then validate?

Comment: Now I see , it is interesting question. The form_for accepts an attribute :validation => true in case you want client side validations . If you don't pass :validation => true , it is not used .

Comment: Yes, but here the validation error-messages appear after I have clicked the submit button. This is server side validation as i have mentioned in the post, but this happens after adding in client_side_validations.rb initializer which is generated by the client_side_validations:install generator.

Comment: You can try commenting out the flash messages in you application.html.erb (or partial , included there) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is right way to do so, but I checked whether the instance responds to an object_name method and changed my code accordingly.

Please find the edited code.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if html_tag =~ /^<label/ or instance.respond_to?(:object_name)
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

The code generated earlier could be seen in the questionare post.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the already correct by Sunil, in case you are using Rubocop, it probably will complain about using `html_safe` and recommends using a helper method instead.

Here is how you change the code by Sunil

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc do |html_tag, instance|
    if html_tag =~ /^<label/
        ApplicationController.helpers.raw("<div class='field_with_errors'>#{html_tag}</div>")
    else
        ApplicationController.helpers.raw("<div class='field_with_errors'>#{html_tag}<label for='#{instance.send(:tag_id)}' class='message'>#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>")
    end
end
```